# Issue with bash alias

Tags: linux, bash

I get the following error

```
find: paths must precede expression: a
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is `"@"`?  Is that the name of a file?

Comment: The original version of this question had information others might find useful.  Not sure if it was intentional, but if the original question were restored it'd make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.  The arguments are in `$@`, not `@`.  Variable interpolation doesn't happen in within single quotes, either.  I only mention those for educational purposes, though, because the ultimate problem is that you can't do argument expansion in an alias: it will evaluate it when declaring the alias, not dynamically when you use the alias.  You have to make a function to do this.  Like so:

```
function makeprivate() { find "$@" -exec chmod go-rwx {} \; ; }
```

Edit: added missing semicolon.